# Facebook login within an iframe (but outside FB)

Tags: php, facebook, iframe

At some point in my application, I use an iframe. In this iframe, some Facebook stuff could be useful and for that, I use the graph API a lot.
Problem is : when someone isn't logged in to facebook or hasn't allowed my application yet, they are prompted to click the "connect with facebook" button. But as soon as they click it, the iframe gets destroyed and the top page is replaced with the Facebook login page. Eventually the top page is redireccted to the previous iframe URL, but the former parent page is lost forever.
Is this the intended behaviour of FB connect ?
Is there a way to avoid it or to hack around it ? (maybe using a popup instead of an iframe, but that sounds ugly (uglier than an iframe)).

I am currently using the PHP SDK

Thanks a lot

Comment: Facebook's login framebusts as a security mechanism. If you want to show a Facebook login window, you do it either full-page or in a popup, not in an iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for opening a pop-up :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

By having an element that trigger the following code on click event :

```
FB.login( callback );
```

it should open a pop-up with the form to login  / authorize your app.

So it involves to not use the ( deprecated ) FBML alternative.

Concerning the iframe element, I doubt you'll find a way to achieve that. The reason is that facebook' script checks the window.top.location to be on facebook domain.

Comment: I'll investigate it. Thing is, I do not use any FBML, all the calls are made through cURL POST in PHP. With such a popup login call, I think the top.window page will be reloaded with the redirect URL. I might be wrong though, thanks for the tip

Comment: Wow ! May I mention ? The only way to achieve "transparent" login is actually using javascript.

Comment: I mean, if the user is already logged in FB, I just catch the token in PHP. Problems happen when they are not. This is why your solution should be fine ;)

Comment: a little bit of follow-up : the FB.login and JS SDK in general works perfectly fine when working with iframes. Thanks again